# problems with adding ;jsessionid in HttpURLconnection in android for GET request

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, jsessionid

In my android Application in the first screen user authenticates and servlet replies with a session id ...
in the second screen the user again calls the servlet with the session id added in the url as ;jsession="sessionid" along with the parameters...

but the servlet is not get the session id and is responding as a new session without authentication...

where is the problem?

i am using this code for the connection

```
                    URL u = new URL(aurl[0]);
        url=aurl[0];
        publishProgress(""+20,"Connecting...");
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        publishProgress(""+40,"Connecting...");
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setDoOutput(true);
        c.connect();

        publishProgress(""+45,"Connecting...");
        publishProgress(""+40,aurl[0]);
        int lenghtOfFile = c.getContentLength();
        System.out.println(lenghtOfFile+"lenghtOfFile");

        is = c.getInputStream();
```

Comment: problem seems to be ;jsessionid=sessionid in the url because of which it is showing Filenotfound exception at is = c.getInputStream(); how do i solve this...

Comment: show your url and how you add jsession

Comment: http://ip/servletname:jsessionid=sessionid?parameters

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem and found a simple solution.

// First set the default cookie manager.

CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));

// All the following subsequent URLConnections will use the same cookie manager.

URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();

// ...

connection = new URL(url).openConnection();

// ...

connection = new URL(url).openConnection();

// ...

This is the simplest solution I found. We need to set default CookieManager.
[Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests) is the great blog.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

adding jseesioid in the url never worked ..
the code worked using this solution

[httpsessionmanagement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2793153/1473896)

especially these two...

```
 // Gather all cookies on the first request.
URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
List<String> cookies = connection.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
// ...

// Then use the same cookies on all subsequent requests.
connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
for (String cookie : cookies) {
connection.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 2)[0]);
 }
 // ...
```

Comment: OMG! Three months trying to find the solution and was here